# New data appears after clicking on button twice

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am making a react-native app which displays the charts based on days

I am dispatching a Redux Action which does an `API` call in `componentDidMount`

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.coinHistory(this.state.days, this.props.navigation.state.params.coinShortName) 
    this.props.coinComplete(this.props.navigation.state.params.coinShortName)
}
```

Intially my state is

```
state = {
    days: 1
}
```

Now, I have a button which changes the above state

```
  <Button
      onPress={() => this.changeHistoryChart(7)}
      title="Learn More"
      color="#841584"
     accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button" />
```

`changeHistoryChart` looks like this

```
   changeHistoryChart = (value) => {
        this.setState({days: value})
this.props.coinHistory(this.state.days, this.props.navigation.state.params.coinShortName) 
    }
```

**[Question:]** While this works, the problem is that I need to click on my button twice to show me the new data or another button to show me that data of previous button. What Could I be doing wrong and how can I fix it? (GIF is attached below for reference)

Also if in case, I am missing any important code then do let me know, I will update it here

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are invoking `onPress` handler immediately:

```
onPress={this.changeHistoryChart(7)}
```

You should use a callback function here, like:

```
onPress={() => this.changeHistoryChart(7)}
```

Also, `setState` is asynchronous so you need a callback if you depend on the updated state for other operations.

```
this.setState({days: value}, () => {
    this.props.coinHistory(this.state.days, this.props.navigation.state.params.coinShortName)
})
```

Comment: Sorry, I already fixed it in my current code but forgot to update here. 
Updated that in my question :)

Comment: Shit! Yes, I forgot setState is asynchronous. This works, Thanks :) 
Will mark it answered after 5 minutes