# Toggle language using React without Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, weather-api

I'm trying to create a weather app in React. I want to toggle the app language using `onClick`.

Here's my code so far.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {

componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      isLoading: true
    });
    axios
      .get("path to weather api")
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data.data[0]);
        const { city_name, temp, weather } = res.data.data[0];
        this.setState({
          loc: city_name,
          temp: temp,
          code: weather.code,
          isLoading: false
        });
        this.setState({
          desc: this.convertCode(this.state.code)
        });
      });
  }

switchLanguage = () => {
    if (this.state.lang === "en") {
      this.setState({
        lang: "hi",
        desc: this.convertCode(this.state.code)
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        lang: "en",
        desc: this.convertCode(this.state.code)
      });
    }
  };

convertCode = givenCode => {
    if (this.state.lang === "en") {
      if (
        givenCode === 200 ||
        givenCode === 201 ||
        givenCode === 202 ||
        givenCode === 230 ||
        givenCode === 231 ||
        givenCode === 232 ||
        givenCode === 233 ||
        givenCode === "200" ||
        givenCode === "201" ||
        givenCode === "202" ||
        givenCode === "230" ||
        givenCode === "231" ||
        givenCode === "232" ||
        givenCode === "233"
      ) {
        return "Thunderstorms";
      } else if (
        givenCode === 300 ||
        givenCode === 301 ||
        givenCode === 302 ||
        givenCode === "300" ||
        givenCode === "301" ||
        givenCode === "302"
      ) {
        return "Drizzle";
      }
      ..............
      ..............
      IF CONDITION FOR THE OTHER LANGUAGE
  };

render() {
    if (!this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <div className="container">
            <div className="languageSwitcher">
              <i className="fa fa-language" onClick={this.switchLanguage} />
            </div>
            <div className="location">
              <i className="fa fa-location-arrow" /> {this.state.loc}
            </div>
            {this.state.lang === "en" && (
              <div className="temperature">It's {this.state.temp} degrees.</div>
            )}
            {this.state.lang === "hi" && (
              <div className="temperature">
                तापमान {this.state.temp} डिग्री है।
              </div>
            )}
            <div className="description">{this.state.desc}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return <div className="loading">Fetching weather data...</div>;
    }
  }
}

export default App;
```

Everything works except for the `div` with `className="desc"`. `desc` is always one phase behind. I mean when `state.lang` is `en`, it displays the text in `hi` and vice-versa.

I just started learning React so the code's pretty messed up. Sorry about that.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean you need to click `onClick` twice for it to work?

Comment: @KuchBhi I think he means that if language is hindi then description comes in english whereas when the language is english then the description comes in hindi.

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52433669/new-data-appears-after-clicking-on-button-twice

Comment: Yes @SivcanSingh is right. The app loads in `en` by default. So when I `onClick` once, the language should change to `hi`, that does happen for all elements except for `desc`. Again in case of `hi` everything becomes `hi` but `desc` becomes `en`. I'm sorry if it's not clear.

Comment: @sequel check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52433669/new-data-appears-after-clicking-on-button-twice

Comment: @KuchBhi I checked it. But it doesn't seem to work for me :(

Comment: *"I just started learning React so the code's pretty messed up."* It could be a **lot** worse. :-) FYI, I briefly deleted [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52441547/157247) because I messed something up. As a result, you may not have seen it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two state management issues and one flow-of-execution issue, one (or possibly more) of which is causing the behavior you mention (but all need fixing in any case):

1. [State updates are asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). This means that `this.state` does **not** have the updated state immediately after a `this.setState` call.
2. Because state updates are asynchronous, if you're setting state based on existing state (which you are in a few places, including `switchLanguage`), you **must** use the version of `setState` you pass a callback to, not the version you pass an object to; in the callback, use the up-to-date state object the callback receives as a parameter.
3. When you do `this.setState({/*...*/desc: this.convertCode(/*...*/)})`, you're calling `convertCode` **before** calling `setState`, and passing its return value into `setState` as a value on a property on the object you're passing it. So even if it weren't for issue #2 above, it would still have a basic flow-of-control issue and `convertCode` would still see the about-to-become-out-of-date `this.state.lang`.

The best way to address all this is probably to update `convertCode` to optionally accept the `lang` to use (defaulting to `this.state.lang`):

```
convertCode = (givenCode, lang = this.state.lang) => {
    // ...use `lang`, not `this.state.lang`...
```

...and then address the various issues setting state and using `convertCode`. The first is in `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      isLoading: true
    });
    axios
      .get("path to weather api")
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data.data[0]);
        const { city_name, temp, weather } = res.data.data[0];
        this.setState({
          loc: city_name,
          temp: temp,
          code: weather.code,
          isLoading: false
        });
        this.setState({
          desc: this.convertCode(this.state.code) // <=== Error is here
        });
      });
  }
```

`this.state.code` won't have been updated yet, because state updates are asynchronous. Also, we want to use `this.state.lang`, so we need to use the callback form. Instead, combine those two calls and pass the lang to `convertCode`:

```
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          loc: city_name,
          temp: temp,
          code: weather.code,
          isLoading: false,
          desc: this.convertCode(weather.code, prevState.lang),
        }));
```

In `switchLanguage`, both problems #2 and #3 exist:

```
// INCORRECT:
//   A) Sets state based on state without callback
//   B) Calls `convertCode` before `setState`
switchLanguage = () => {
    if (this.state.lang === "en") {
      this.setState({
        lang: "hi",
        desc: this.convertCode(this.state.code)
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        lang: "en",
        desc: this.convertCode(this.state.code)
      });
    }
  };
```

We can fix both issues by using the callback form and passing the language to use into `convertCode`:

```
// Uses callback when setting state based on state
switchLanguage = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const lang = prevState.lang === "en" ? "hi": "en";
      return {lang, desc: this.convertCode(prevState.code, lang)};
    });
  };
```

Notice the use of `prevState` both for the `lang` check and for passing `code` to `this.convertCode`.

Comment: @sequel - I think some error must have been introduced in the process, or perhaps something in your app isn't quite as it seems. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Wait. My version of `convertCode` has got ony one param: `givenCode`. Since you're telling me to pass two params to `convertCode`, I'll have to change the function definition of `convertCode`. Right?

Comment: @sequel - Right, I've shown doing that near the top of the answer. The other code in the answer relies on that. (It's not the only way to address the problem, but it's probably the simplest and most efficient.)

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to edit my function and let you know.

Comment: Okay. Finally, it's working. My bad, I didn't notice `convertCode = (givenCode, lang = this.state.lang)` that you mentioned at the top. Thanks again. You're great.

Comment: @sequel - No worries! Glad that helped.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the previous lang state in `convertCode` method, you may pass the new lang to it instead :

```
convertCode = (givenCode, lang) => {
    if (lang === "en") {
        ...
```

Then in your `switchLanguage` method :

```
this.setState({
        lang: "hi",
        desc: this.convertCode(this.state.code, "hi")
      });
```

**Edit**: Prefer the functional version of setState to avoid inconsistencies in case `this.state.code` updates:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
        lang: "hi",
        desc: this.convertCode(prevState.code, "hi")
      }));
```

Comment: I think we can trust the value of `this.state.code` in this case because it has no way to be updated in a batch with the language switch.

Comment: I agree but I don't think everybody must blindly follow this rule as it can prevent batching state updates and may cause performance issues in some specific cases.

Comment: @Dyo I tried what you said but it wasn't working. I appreciate that you tried to help me out. Thanks.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Good point, but the issue here isn't about 'setState is async'. This issue is about `convertCode` called before setting the new state (correct me if I'm wrong you wrote 'after' in your answer)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  I'll try my best to spread the word, I just thought how hard it can be to debug (and to reproduce) a data inconsistency due to a state batching, so better play safe ! Thank you, I enjoyed the debate.

Comment: @Dyo - :-) I appreciated the perspective. After all, if you *know* `code` can't change... Useful to keep in mind. Happy coding!